# Center textarea text vertically if only one row with text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got a textarea that is 2 rows high. When there is just one row of text in the textarea it looks like this:
[image]

What I'm looking for is a way to make it look like this if only one row got text:
[image]

When there are 2 rows in the textarea with text, I want it to look normal like this:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
<textarea class='input_box_menu'>Test text</textarea>

.input_box_menu {
    text-align: center;
    width: 217px;
    height: 35px;
    resize: none;
    float: left;
}
```

*Help really appreciated!

Thanks,

Tompa*

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS please.

Comment: Please share your HTML and css

Comment: Not much code, but I edited my post.

Comment: read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align and see what it applies to and you should be able to answer yourself.

Comment: @pattmorter I tried all the different types of 'vertical-align', neither of them makes any difference at all. Not even a pixel!

Comment: http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/gICqd USE THIS LINK IT WILL SOLVE YOUR PROBLEM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little jQuery snippet to do exactly what you wish to do:

```
$(function () {
    fixVAlign($('.input_box_menu'));
    $('.input_box_menu').on('keyup', function () {
        fixVAlign($(this))
    });
});

function fixVAlign(field) {
    if (field.val().length < 27) {
        field.css('line-height', '35px');
    } else {
        field.css('line-height', 'normal');
    }
}
```

**And here the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aLRs7/1/)**

Comment: This does seems to be the best (and only?) way to do it! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so my first train of thought was to look up the css property `vertical-align` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align).

> Applies to: **inline-level** and **table-cell** elements

So looking at your example, inline-level objects seem to be out of the question -- so why not table cell?

Try this out:

```
.box {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    background: #d4d4d4;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```
<div class="box">
    Text Text Text
</div>
```

Just a side note, there are ways to do this with a `span` within a `div` or a `div` withing a `div`, this is just how I chose to interpret the question.

**EDIT**

Ignore my answer because it doesn't do anything about textareas.

[See this pen on CodePen for an example of a good fix.](http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/gICqd)

Comment: This does center the text vertically as it should, However! When I try with a textarea instead of div it gets stuck in the top as usual

Comment: @Tompa i didn't even notice the word text area... i should probably start reading lol. let me fix my answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Because you say you can use JavaScript, the simplest way to do this would be to set the initial `line-height` of the `<textarea>` equal to its initial `height`. Then `onkeypress` or a similar JavaScript event you can check `textarea.value.length` and if it's long enough to wrap, then you would set the line-height back to the `font-size`.

Comment: Sorry that won't work. \n is not accepted in the field

Comment: @Tompa So the only way to have multiple lines is if the text is very long?